# Parameters for extracted .exe setup

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, installation

I have a `SampleApp.exe`. When I double click it, it extracts itself into a folder (lets say a folder name `SampleAppFolder` and YES it do ask for a folderpath) and starts a Setup.exe from that folder (`Setup.exe` is extracted in `SampleAppFolder`). I want to run `SampleApp.exe` in silent mode. So I created a batch file as

```
"D:\Softwares\SampleApp.exe" /S /V" /quiet"
```

Everything gets extracted in SampleAppFolder silently but when it triggers Setup.exe from the folder, I am able to see a window. But I wanted to run even this .exe in silent mode. So I guess I need to pass some parameters for this setup.exe also. But I am not sure how. Any pointers please?

On more thing, I changed the above query as

```
"D:\Softwares\SampleApp.exe" /extract"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\TestFiles123" /S /V" /quiet"
```

I thought the extraction path will change, but nothing happened and the files got extracted to default location again. Any pointers? Thanks

Comment: Did you write the app yourself?

Comment: no....its product of a company....

Answer (score 0):

Try opening it up in 7-zip. It can extract files from most installers and you can choose where to extract them (and which ones if you're only looking for a couple).

[7-Zip Website Link](http://www.7-zip.org/)

Comment: thanks Christopher......I have already tries it but of not much use....still I am digging into it...thanks again