# Get parameters from WiX packed .EXE

Tags: batch-file, wix, windows-installer, silent

[Few days back I asked a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237073/parameters-for-extracted-exe-setup)

I have an application that is using `WiX (Windows Installer XML)` as a package manager to create a `.exe` file with some supporting files (folders and `.dlls`). Double clicking this `.exe` will extract into a new folder and `Setup.exe` will run from that location. I just wanted to know if I can get the parameters for this `.exe` and also of `Setup.exe` so that I can create a batch file to install the complete application silently.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately without knowing what the Setup.exe is made with it'll be very difficult. To me it just sounds like it is a normal program if dll's are dropped next to it.

However if it is a Burn created bootstrapper you switch on logging by running with the following commandline:

```
Setup.exe -log "%CD%\installLog.txt"
```

you will be able to see any variables that are being setup by looking for lines similar to:

```
[2013-01-10T11:20:09]: Initializing string variable 'SqlServer' to value '(local)'
[2013-01-10T11:20:09]: Initializing string variable 'SqlInstance' to value 'SQLEXPRESS'
[2013-01-10T11:20:09]: Initializing string variable 'SqlAdminUser' to value 'sa'
[2013-01-10T11:20:09]: Initializing hidden variable 'SqlAdminUserPassword'
```

Comment: I ran the command like `Setup.exe -log "C:\Software\InstallationLog.txt"`...software is installing but no log file created. I hope I ran it correctly.

Comment: @rapsalands By default, Burn should log to the current user's temp directory. Check there.

Comment: I am fariad but its not happening

Comment: I doubt that it is made with wix then. What you could try is to decompile it with a dotnet decompiler such as http://ilspy.net/ to see if you can see any parameters that you can supply to it.